# Create thumbnail image Nativescript

Tags: angular, nativescript

I am building an app using Angular and I use `cardview` for showing images. I am looking for a way to achieve that a tap on the image opens it in a larger scale and also plays a video by tapping on it.

Comment: sorry i didn't understand

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can help you with specific coding questions, but it is expected that you have researched your issue and made a good attempt to write the code yourself.